# Laptop Precision 7530 BIOS passwd reset

Tags: bios

Is there any way to reset a BIOS passwd? The old version of hash calculators doesn't work. It is a new laptop and I wnated to use standard checksum calculation method to reset it but it doesn't generate any suitable passwd.

Comment: If it's then is has UEFI, not BIOS, and no, old calculators don't work.

Comment: * If it's new then...

Comment: I am not sure, if we are talking about the same passwd :). I meant the one for modification of BIOS parameters (eg. switch on/off built-in graphic card etc.), not preventing system boot after start of the PC. the BIOS behaves exactly the same way as on the PC one month older, where the bios-pw worked pretty well, but here it doesn't give me any usefull one. Do do have any suggestion?